# Windows 10 assigned access app fails to start due to not registered for Windows.Launch contract

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, kiosk

I have a WPF application, which I have converted to a UWP application using the `DesktopAppConverter` for the purposes of running it in *Assigned Access* mode - the converted app works when run in non-assigned access mode - can be installed and functions properly.

However, when I set it up to be used as an assigned access application and log in with the account for assigned access, the screen keeps flashing (blue screen with loading dots, followed by a white screen, and repeat) for a period of time, resulting in the 0x80270254 error displayed.

Also after checking the Windows Event Logs I get two error messages in succession:

1. The application MyAppName is not registered for the Windows.Launch contract or is not installed.
2. ActivateApplicationForContractByAppIdAsUserWithHost of the app MyAppName for the Windows.Launch contract failed with This app does not support the contract specified or is not installed.

I've been trying to debug the app, including making changes to the AppxManifest.xml file and rebuilding the .appx package, making changes to the properties of the original WPF app that it came from and making changes to the Assigned Access user account's environment with little to no success.

Any tips for the resolution of the issue would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this issue.

We got the confirmation that the Assigned Access mode **doesn’t support Win32 apps yet, including Win32 apps converted with the Desktop Converter**.

*It is a known issue in RS1 which can pick Converted app in setting UI.* We have a planned fix for this in RS2 but do not guarantee it will be delivered soon.

Please see this article for how to use Shell Launcher to config a kiosk device that runs a Classic Windows application as the user interface: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows/manage/set-up-a-kiosk-for-windows-10-for-desktop-editions

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Will give it a go.

Comment: Can you confirm whether this made it into 15063? I am trying to get it working on the creators update (though my dev machine is still 14393) and still cannot make it work though the application runs fine when launched manually.

Comment: Is it still true that Win32 programs aren't supported?