# Cannot get windows 10 assigned access work with Electron-Windows-Store

Tags: windows, uwp, windows-10, electron, kiosk-mode

I have created an electron app distributable as Windows Store Application by using [`electron-windows-store`](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/electron-windows-store).

After installing the `.appx` package I'm able to launch it and use it without any problem, but when I try to setup an assigned access for a Standard User with the same App the application fails to startup.

Syntoms are the same that are state in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40492539/windows-10-assigned-access-app-fails-to-start-due-to-not-registered-for-windows) other StackOverflow question, but the answer does not apply to my case, because the generated package is 64-bit.

I'm not able to find any other clue about the reason why it fails, so I don't know whats wrong.

Comment: Since it looks like, probably, the Windows.FullTrustApplication entry point (used by the electron windows store application) is not supported by Assigned Access, I've posted my idea on Windows Developers Feedback. If anyone is interested can vote the idea or improve it [here](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/17450752-assigned-access-not-working-with-electron)